# Town Hall Grid?

Tags: clash-of-clans

So I was looking at my friend's base and he was raided I noticed a weird grid under his Destroyed Town Hall.  It's a square grid that starts from the outside with the color Yellow and gradients it's way to the inside to red squares.  Any ideas what this is?

[image: Town Hall 10 (Destructed)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Hall)**

> When a level 10 Town Hall is destroyed, the ruins are lying on a grate
> on top of lava.

Also, it is stated that

> The lava in the level 10 Town Hall may be a reference to the fact that
> the Inferno Towers are unlocked at this level.

So, basically it is a metal grate (probably on which the town hall is placed) and below it there is lava.

Comment: Ahhh, I See.  Whenever I looked at it the first time I saw it as Squares floating above a vast cavity under the TH, but now that I look closer I see the grate.